# classNotFoundException when trying to use Oracle JdbcOdbcDriver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have successfully installed an ODBC driver. I am trying to connect to an Oracle 10g database using Netbeans 7.0.

During connectivity it says "Driver class missing".

How can this be fixed?

Error:

> java.lang.classNotFoundException:oracle.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

```
try
{
    // Load the JDBC driver       
    String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    Class.forName(driverName);           
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:placement");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Connection Established");

     ///unrelated code snipped            
}
```

Comment: You may have 'installed' the JDBC driver, but you haven't put the jar file containing it into your classpath.

Comment: for example http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/oracle-db.html

Comment: @bmargulies: the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver is a standard part of any Windows JRE.  There's no need to install it or put a JAR anywhere, it should just work.

Comment: @Luke, oh, that old thing. I didn't realize he was making the mistake of trying to use it, as opposed to the real JDBC driver.

Comment: Is there a reason for using the JDBC ODBC bridge. Maybe you can use the Oracle Thin driver, a type 4 JDBC driver implemented in pure Java. It does not have the overhead in bridging from ODBC to JDBC and back to ODBC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've got the name of the class wrong.  Try `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` instead.